# Retrieving Django Unittest result in view

Tags: django, django-unittest

I can't find this anywhere, but is it possible to run a unittest from within a django view, to be output to a template? Currently if I run `python manage.py test`, I get a message like "`Ran 10 tests in 0.401s OK`". I would like to access this information from one of my views. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Edit: Tried, didnt work:

```
import StringIO
from django.core import manegement
output = StringIO.StringIO()
management.call_command('test', stdout=output)
print output.contents
```

Comment: This might be a crude way to do it, but try [`call_command`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#call-command)

Comment: If you just need a web interface to view your test results, use a CI tool like buildbot, instead of creating your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up getting what I wanted with:

```
import unittest
from testAdditional import UserTestCase #Where my unittest was defined
suite=unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(UserTestCase)
testResult = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
response_data['nrFailed'] = len(testResult.failures)
response_data['output'] = "{}{}".format('\n'.join([result[1] for result in testResult.errors]),'\n'.join([result[1] for result in testResult.failures]))
response_data['totalTests'] = testResult.testsRun
```